# CSS SVG Animation for a Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a mockup image for a svg css animation for a slider here and want to implement this in css.

The animation consists of a ballon with the current number value and should be zoomed in and out from left to right or right to left.

Currently i'm at the starting point and a bit lost how to solve this. The main problem for me is how to zoom this ballon in or out, so the front balloon is overlapping the 2 balloons in the background.

Does anyone has a similar sample or can point me in the right direction how to solve this?

Would be great, thanks!

Updated:

Excuse my poor drawing skills, but i hope this explains it better:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I correctly understood that the middle balloon should expand and overlap two other adjacent balloons?

Comment: Yes, and it should be used for a slider, when changing the value, maybe from 3 to 4, it should move the current balloon at the right position to the foreground in the middle in an animation and dispay a 4. And the past balloon with the 3 to the background at the right position in an animation. I hope i explained it well. ;)

Comment: words are understood in different ways It would be nice if you add a second screenshot of how it should look after the end of the animation

Comment: Excuse my poor drawing skills.. added another image, which i hope it does explain it better.

Comment: Still not sure I understand the intent, are you trying to make like a carousel for the bubble thingy's that they rotate on and +/- their scale based on the value of a slider element? I'm not sure how slider plays into this really, either way I don't see any attempt on your own yet, just requirements...

Comment: yes, i want to make a carousel. The slider is an extra control. The bubbles are for the display above the slider.

Comment: Yea then sorry bro, that's more work than personally I'd be willing to volunteer for free.....but if you make a go at it and get stuck with something in particular in your attempt will check back. You're going to be getting into 3d rotate transforms, scaling, and wiring it up to be controlled by the slider....imo this is just a "hey will someone do this for me" kind of inquiry as opposed to an actual question.

Answer (score 2):

*I did according to the words in the question*

> The main problem for me is how to zoom this ballon in or out, so the
> front balloon is overlapping the 2 balloons in the background.

When you hover over the middle ball, it increases in size and overlaps two adjacent balls

```css
#middle {
transform-origin:center;
transform-box:fill-box;

}
#middle:hover {
animation:scaled  0.8s linear forwards;
fill:#CDA349;
} 

@keyframes scaled {
100%{transform:scale(2.1);}
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="440" height="440" viewBox="-50 -50 550 550">
    <g fill="#F1C056">
  
  <path d="M311.4 157.5c14.2-4.3 34.3 6.6 46.1 18.2a44.3 44.3 0 0 1 12.6 30.3c.1 23.4-14.8 44.8-26.1 65.3-7.4 13.4-15.2 22.8-27 37.3-8.1-11-18.4-23.8-27.6-40.1 5.9-14 14.6-27.6 19.6-42.2 3.8-11 7.5-22.2 8-33.8.4-11.8-2.7-18-5.6-35z"  />
  <path d="M125.6 160.8c-9.6-5.8-23.1-4.8-33.8-1.2a55.7 55.7 0 0 0-35.4 58.5c3.1 14.2 11 27.1 17.8 40a277 277 0 0 0 16.4 26.5c5.6 8.3 11 17 18 24 14.5-20.6 22-30.4 33-51.3-4-12.9-13-26.4-16.7-40.6a111.2 111.2 0 0 1-4.3-33.3c.3-7.7 3-12.7 5-22.6z"   />
  <path id="middle"  d="M218.6 355.2a469 469 0 0 1-46.5-69.5c-15-28.4-32.4-52.7-38.3-79.7a89.4 89.4 0 0 1 20-73.6 89 89 0 0 1 65.7-28.5 91.2 91.2 0 0 1 64.4 29.4c14.9 16.7 25 41.8 21 63.9-6 32.4-24.9 60.1-40.6 88.5a492.4 492.4 0 0 1-45.7 69.5z" />
   </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Alexandr_TT

Great, this is going in the right direction. I implemented it in js as a caroussel slide animation, but want to implement this as a single svg animation like the image in the initial post for display only.

Here is my Code:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Animation</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">" media="screen">
        <style>
            * { box-sizing: border-box; }
    
            body { font-family: sans-serif; }
    
            .carousel {
                background: white;
            }
    
            .carousel-cell {
                width: 70%;
                height: 200px;
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -webkit-flex;
                display:         flex;
                -webkit-box-pack: center;
                -webkit-justify-content: center;
                justify-content: center;
                -webkit-align-items: center;
                align-items: center;
            }
    
            .carousel-cell svg {
                display: block;
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
                opacity: 1;
                -webkit-transform: scale(0.85);
                transform: scale(0.85);
                -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, -webkit-transform 0.8s, transform 0.8s, -webkit-filter 0.8s, filter 0.8s;
                transition: opacity 1s, transform 0.8s, filter 0.8s;
            }
    
            .carousel-cell.is-selected svg {
                opacity: 1;
                -webkit-transform: scale(2);
                transform: scale(2);
                -webkit-filter: none;
                filter: none;
            }
    
            @media screen and ( min-width: 768px ) {
                .carousel-cell {
                    height: 400px;
                }
            }
    
            @media screen and ( min-width: 960px ) {
                .carousel-cell {
                    width: 10%;
                }
            }
            .flickity-prev-next-button {
                width: 60px;
                height: 60px;
                background: transparent;
                opacity: 1;
            }
            .flickity-prev-next-button:hover {
                background: transparent;
                opacity: 1;
            }
            /* arrow color */
            .flickity-prev-next-button .arrow {
                fill: white;
            }
            .flickity-prev-next-button.no-svg {
                color: white;
            }
            /* closer to edge */
            .flickity-prev-next-button.previous { left: 0; }
            .flickity-prev-next-button.next { right: 0; }
            /* hide disabled button */
            .flickity-prev-next-button:disabled {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="carousel js-flickity">
        <div class="carousel-cell">
            <svg width="440" height="440" viewBox="-50 -50 550 550" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <g fill="#F1C056" transform="matrix(0.464127, 0, 0, 0.464127, 108.349289, 107.221474)" style="">
                    <path id="left" d="M218.6 355.2a469 469 0 0 1-46.5-69.5c-15-28.4-32.4-52.7-38.3-79.7a89.4 89.4 0 0 1 20-73.6 89 89 0 0 1 65.7-28.5 91.2 91.2 0 0 1 64.4 29.4c14.9 16.7 25 41.8 21 63.9-6 32.4-24.9 60.1-40.6 88.5a492.4 492.4 0 0 1-45.7 69.5z"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
            <svg width="440" height="440" viewBox="-50 -50 550 550" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <g fill="#F1C056" transform="matrix(0.464127, 0, 0, 0.464127, 108.349289, 107.221474)" style="">
                    <path id="middle" d="M218.6 355.2a469 469 0 0 1-46.5-69.5c-15-28.4-32.4-52.7-38.3-79.7a89.4 89.4 0 0 1 20-73.6 89 89 0 0 1 65.7-28.5 91.2 91.2 0 0 1 64.4 29.4c14.9 16.7 25 41.8 21 63.9-6 32.4-24.9 60.1-40.6 88.5a492.4 492.4 0 0 1-45.7 69.5z"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
            <svg width="440" height="440" viewBox="-50 -50 550 550" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <g fill="#F1C056" transform="matrix(0.464127, 0, 0, 0.464127, 108.349289, 107.221474)" style="">
                    <path id="right" d="M218.6 355.2a469 469 0 0 1-46.5-69.5c-15-28.4-32.4-52.7-38.3-79.7a89.4 89.4 0 0 1 20-73.6 89 89 0 0 1 65.7-28.5 91.2 91.2 0 0 1 64.4 29.4c14.9 16.7 25 41.8 21 63.9-6 32.4-24.9 60.1-40.6 88.5a492.4 492.4 0 0 1-45.7 69.5z"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```